# Error por consola al querer ejecutar el método toUpperCase en un algoritmo en Javascript

Tags: javascript, validación, vscode

Hay un error que aparece al querer ejecutar el algoritmo pero no encuentro el por qué ya que por la consola aparece "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toUpperCase')" en la línea 11, es decir, en el else, pero no veo el fallo... sospecho que quizás está en la validación del if

```js
let nombre = prompt("ingrese su nombre en Mayuscula");
let edad = parseInt(prompt("ingrese con numeros su edad"));
const ACTUAL = 2021;
const ESPACIO = " ";
const FRASE = "Usted pertenece a la generación";
let nacimiento = ACTUAL - edad;

if ((nombre != "") && (isNaN(nombre)) && (nombre == nombre.toUpperCase())) {
  console.log("Bienvenido" + ESPACIO + nombre.toUpperCase() + "\n");
} else {
  alert("Hola" + ESPACIO + nombre.toUpperCase() + " Debería practicar más su lectura, debe ingresar su nombre en MAYUSCULA \n");
  nombre = prompt("ingrese su nombre en Mayuscula");
}
if ((nacimiento < 1946) || (nacimiento > 2025)) {
  console.log(nombre + ESPACIO + ("ingreso un valor no permitido. O es muy viejo o todavíano ha nacido"));
} else if ((nacimiento >= 1946) && (nacimiento <= 1964)) {
  console.log(nombre + ESPACIO + FRASE + ESPACIO + "Baby boomers");
} else if ((nacimiento >= 1965) && (nacimiento <= 1980)) {
  console.log(nombre + ESPACIO + FRASE + ESPACIO + "X");
} else if ((nacimiento >= 1981) && (nacimiento <= 1999)) {
  console.log(nombre + ESPACIO + FRASE + ESPACIO + "Millennials");
} else if ((nacimiento >= 2000) && (nacimiento <= 2010)) {
  console.log(nombre + ESPACIO + FRASE + ESPACIO + "Z");
} else if ((nacimiento >= 2011) && (nacimiento <= 2021)) {
  console.log(nombre + ESPACIO + FRASE + ESPACIO + "Alfa");
} else {
  console.error("Error, el valor ingresado no es valido.");
}
```

Comment: No se cual es tu error... Copie y pegué tu codigo en una consola online y me funciona todo, no tira ningun error

Comment: Tenés razón @AlfaRojo pero hace rato me dió error en el VSC... quizás era algo que quedó en caché pues cerré la extensión Live Server y lo puse a andar de nuevo y si funcionó... en este caso que publiqué algo que no tiene fallo, ¿debería eliminar la publicación o dar yo mismo mi respuesta y aclarar lo sucedido?

Comment: Si no hay entrada del usuario y se preciona el boton de aceptar del `prompt` entonces retornará nulo y no una cadena, usa un `console.log(nombre);` para ver que contenido tiene antes de usar la funcion del string.

Comment: Exactamente eso fue lo que me pasó @DanielBriceño, tal cual.

Comment: Si, hace tiempo ese mismo error me dió un dolor de cabeza.

Comment: Me disculpo, intento reproducir el error, pero no lo logro.

Comment: Si @DanielBriceño, tal como coloqué en los comentarios, ya no hay error, pues el error era el que comentas, que daba Enter sin introducir nada y entonces arrojaba 'null'

Answer (score 0):

Intente esto

```
let nombre = prompt("ingrese su nombre en Mayuscula");
let edad = parseInt(prompt("ingrese con numeros su edad"));
const ACTUAL = 2021;
const ESPACIO = " ";
const FRASE = "Usted pertenece a la generación";
let nacimiento = ACTUAL - edad;

while (nombre !== null){
    nombre = prompt("ingrese un valor,ingrese su nombre en Mayuscula");
}
while (edad !== null){
    edad = parseInt(prompt("ingrese un valor,ingrese con numeros su edad"));
    nacimiento = ACTUAL - edad;
}
if ((nombre != "") && (isNaN(nombre)) && (nombre == nombre.toUpperCase())) {
    console.log("Bienvenido" + ESPACIO + nombre.toUpperCase() + "\n");
} else {
  alert("Hola" + ESPACIO + nombre.toUpperCase() + " Debería practicar más su lectura, debe ingresar su nombre en MAYUSCULA \n");
  nombre = prompt("ingrese su nombre en Mayuscula");
}
if ((nacimiento < 1946) || (nacimiento > 2025)) {
  console.log(nombre + ESPACIO + ("ingreso un valor no permitido. O es muy viejo o todavíano ha nacido"));
} else if ((nacimiento >= 1946) && (nacimiento <= 1964)) {
  console.log(nombre + ESPACIO + FRASE + ESPACIO + "Baby boomers");
} else if ((nacimiento >= 1965) && (nacimiento <= 1980)) {
  console.log(nombre + ESPACIO + FRASE + ESPACIO + "X");
} else if ((nacimiento >= 1981) && (nacimiento <= 1999)) {
  console.log(nombre + ESPACIO + FRASE + ESPACIO + "Millennials");
} else if ((nacimiento >= 2000) && (nacimiento <= 2010)) {
  console.log(nombre + ESPACIO + FRASE + ESPACIO + "Z");
} else if ((nacimiento >= 2011) && (nacimiento <= 2021)) {
  console.log(nombre + ESPACIO + FRASE + ESPACIO + "Alfa");
} else {
  console.error("Error, el valor ingresado no es valido.");
}
```

y deberia funcionar

Comment: hola TroxZ, bienvenido y gracias por tu colaboración, antes de contestar, es buena idea , no solo leer detenidamente la pregunta, sino también los comentarios, si lo hubieses hecho, sabrías que, A) la pregunta fue formulada hace año y medio (esto tal vez te quite las ganas de responder), B) que en realidad no había ningún problema en el código (tampoco ayuda a las ganas), por otro lado, las respuestas que son solo código, están consideradas de baja calidad, cuando respondas, asegurate de explicar como tu propuesta resuelve el problema planteado.